# Notepad++ add one line multiple places

Tags: notepad++

Manipulating large xml data files for testing purposes. The newest version of our software will require a new child element under a parent element that repeats every hour. Can I add this new child element after the previous child element without doing each hour individually? I've read about macros, but I'd rather not play a macro 720+ times, its really not much faster than just retyping by the time I've found the line to put it after.

Comment: What does your xml file look like, and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://imgur.com/lw5Bb70). I want to make all these instances look like [this](http://imgur.com/KDkZluN).

Comment: The sample content needs to be *here*, in your question itself. The question is meaningless without it, and if the off-site location is unavailable it can't be retrieved, meaning your entire question will have no value to future readers here. Please [edit] to provide a representative sample of the before and after XML.

Comment: @blueyed1dr What Ken White said, and also, when you edit, please don't put an _image_ in your post. We want text, not images.